# React useEffect track all values available in dependency array best practice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

Take a situation like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const TestComponent = () => {
  const [remoteUser, setRemoteUser] = useState()
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState()

  //...

  useEffect(() => {
    if (remoteUser && socket) {
      socket.on('userState', (data) => {
        handleUserStateChange({ data, remoteUser })
      })
    }
  }, [remoteUser, socket])

  //...
}
```

I usually have to check if both remoteUser and socket is truthy in useEffect's dependency array.

Is there a better way or is this the optimal method of making sure all values in useEffect's dependency array are available because I need both values to use the functions associated.

Comment: so what happens when the socket changed? do you need to close the old socket? if yes, you can do proper cleanup by returning something in `useEffect`

Comment: Do you want to run useEffect when both values have changed or when both values are available. Well if you want both the values to be available then yes the above approach is correct. However you must cleanup the socket listener too

Comment: @Shubham Khatri I want to run useEffect(...) when both values are available

Comment: @mding5692 In such a case the method that you use is correct. just add a cleanup of socket event in useEffect

Comment: @JosephD. I get and set a new remoteUser each time from socket messages that are sent out from a socketio server couple minutes after the next in another socket client listener; I start the socket connection in another function

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yep will add the cleanup, thanks for reminding me, also going to edit title to reflect use case of all values available

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer: this may not make sense given your particular context but I still wanted to take a shot in the dark here.

It's best practice to create the dependencies within the effect if possible. You can also set state within the effect too.

Try something like this:

```js
function MyComp({ userId }) {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // just use this as an example, you can create the socket
    // instance here, but you'll most likely have some sort of
    // deps needed to create your socket
    const socket = new ExampleSocket(`/foo/bar/${userId}`);

    const handleUserStateChange = ({ data, remoteUser }) => {
      setSomeState({ data, removeUser });
    };

    socket.on('userState', (data) => {
      handleUserStateChange({ data, remoteUser })
    })

    return () => {
      // don't forget to clean up your effects
      socket.close();
    }
  }, [userId]);

  return // ...
}
```

**Why?**

Because creating these values inside the effect isolates them as a smaller side effect with less dependencies and less state — both are hard to manage so less is better.

Comment: Thats an interesting way but if I need to use the socket outside the useEffect(...) hook, how would that work? I would still need it for example if a user pressed some button and thus I need to emit data from my socket, guess still a different context, think this approach would work if no interaction with socket outside the useEffect(...) hook